# How to sort rows based on column combinations - python

Tags: python, database, data-science

Is there a way to sort a dataframe by a combination of different columns? As in if specific columns match among rows, they will be clustered together? An example below: Any help is greatly appreciated!

[Original DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9JO2.png)

[Transformed DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMHCJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

One way to sort pandas dataframe is to use .sort_values().

The code below replicates your sample dataframe:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'v1': [1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3],
                  'v2': [2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2],
                  'v3': [3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
                  'v4': [4, 5, 1, 4, 2, 5]})
```

Using the code below, can sort the dataframe by both column v1 and v2. In this case, v2 is only used to break ties.

```
df.sort_values(by=['v1', 'v2'], ascending=True)
```

"by" parameter here is not limited to any number of variables, so could extend the list to include more variables in desired order.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best to match your sort pattern shown in the image.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    v1=[1,3,2,1,4,3],
    v2=[2,2,4,2,3,2],
    v3=[3,3,2,3,2,3],
    v4=[4,5,1,4,2,5],
))

# Make a temp column to sort the df by
df['sort'] = df.astype(str).values.sum(axis=1)
# Sort the df by that column, drop it and reset the index
df = df.sort_values(by='sort').drop(columns='sort').reset_index(drop=1)

print(df)
```

Link you can refe - [Code in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20v1%3D%5B1,3,2,1,4,3%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20v2%3D%5B2,2,4,2,3,2%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20v3%3D%5B3,3,2,3,2,3%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20v4%3D%5B4,5,1,4,2,5%5D,%0A%29%29%0A%0A%23%20Make%20a%20temp%20column%20to%20sort%20the%20df%20by%0Adf%5B%27sort%27%5D%20%3D%20df.astype%28str%29.values.sum%28axis%3D1%29%0A%23%20Sort%20the%20df%20by%20that%20column,%20drop%20it%20and%20reset%20the%20index%0Adf%20%3D%20df.sort_values%28by%3D%27sort%27%29.drop%28columns%3D%27sort%27%29.reset_index%28drop%3D1%29%0A%0Aprint%28df%29%0A%20%20%20%20&cumulative=true&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Edit: Zolzaya Luvsandorj's recommendation is better:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    v1=[1,3,2,1,4,3],
    v2=[2,2,4,2,3,2],
    v3=[3,3,2,3,2,3],
    v4=[4,5,1,4,2,5],
))

df = df.sort_values(by=list(df.columns)).reset_index(drop=1)

print(df)
```

Link you can refe - [Better code in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20v1%3D%5B1,3,2,1,4,3%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20v2%3D%5B2,2,4,2,3,2%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20v3%3D%5B3,3,2,3,2,3%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20v4%3D%5B4,5,1,4,2,5%5D,%0A%29%29%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20df.sort_values%28by%3Dlist%28df.columns%29%29.reset_index%28drop%3D1%29%0Aprint%28df%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)